# How to force the FS312F (DW01A-G) battery protection IC to automatically enable itself when reaching the overdischarge release voltage or above

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, circuit-protection, over-discharge, tp4056

The IC successfully cuts off the battery when the voltage goes below 2.9V (2.4V with DW01-G), but it doesn't reactivate itself when it is reaching its overdischarge release voltage. I would like to add some logic which is monitoring the voltage level of the battery and reactivating the circuitry by enabling the discharge mosfet trhough the chip select pin.

Another problem which would be solved by such a solution is the necessity of plugging in a charger, when connecting a fully charged battery for the first time to the circuitry in order to make it running. You can find a note for this case in the datasheet:

[image]

I ended up with the following shematic, where the CS (chip select) pin is pulled to ground by a 3904 NPN transistor as soon as the MAX809S voltage detector (reset/supervisor/monitor) IC is getting triggered - means the reset pin is set to HIGH at 3.2V or above, which is the case with a fully chared battery. This should have the positve effect that the circuitry is directly working without the need of plugging in the charger after inserting a battery for the first time in order to make it running.

**Updated due to comments:**

[image]

Like mentioned in the comments this is not working because U1 and Q1 are controlling the path to BAT- and thus there is no correct voltage measuring possible.

**Here is a new try**: I replaced the 3904 NPN transistor with a N-Channel Mosfet to reduce the current draw and connected it directly to the Battery, while respecting the battery cell reverse connection protection (Q2):

[image]

Any concerns about this new one?

1. maybe it is still not the right way to do or
2. maybe I should add some resistors somewhere or
3. maybe it is still drawing too much current or
4. maybe it is even dangerous, because this is bypassing some important safety features?

Comment: Your cct shows what works for you - but not the cct that doesn't work. || Possibly relevant: Q1 is in the low side of the ouput cct and cuts off output ground.  The DW01 handles this by having its own ground connected from pin 6 to at -ve. This stays connecte3d when Q1 is off. It is not obvious how you cct works as U3 is sensing between main ground and AT+ BUT bat is floating wrt main gnd due to U1 -  so why does U3 correctly monitor Vbat ?

Comment: Think carefully about tghis: The battery low voltage cct used with TP4056on mullions of modules "just works" what are you doing that doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know why it is correctly monitoring the battery voltage, but it is. I can upload a video if you want. Also maybe this will clearify the problem: As soon it is reaching the 2,9V it is getting into power-down mode and then it requires the user to plug in a charger to restore the normal condition otherwise it stays off. so if I power on the circuitry and there is a voltage drop because f.e. an initial high resistance of a mosfet or a boost converter it is getting into sleep.

Comment: Video not wanted. What doesn't work in standard millions-made TP4056 cct is needed to be explained. The asian sourced modules 'just work'. What are you doing that is not identical to what vthey do? Why are you not doing identically to what they do. There may be reasons but we do not know them if you di not tell us.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Actually you are right, and usually I'm a fan of using stuff like it was ment to, but in this case I think it does make sense. Pls look at the updated OP for clarifying things out.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Ok, yes indeed, connecting to the common ground is not working, and connecting to BAT- is causing a constant current draw of 7mA in power-down mode, also in this case it would be in parallel with the reverse voltage protection Q2, thus not protected against battery cell reverse connection. Is there a workaround else?

Comment: It's easy to seek to explain things without realising that people do not understand what your basic need is. This is happening here. This is a not uncommon problem. | I  still do not know what your actual question is, what your problem with the original cct is and what you are trying to achieve. Instead of describing what you did to try to fix your problem PLEASE spell out in simple words what your actual requirement is and what your problem is. Do not at this stage tell us how you trued to fix things. Tell us what the need and the problem is.

Comment: You have not addressed the key points in my prior query. Q1.What is wrong with the std solution that works for millions of people? Q2. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your new cct gives the reset IC a proper battery ref but now you are pulling U1-CS down to a floating :ground" which MAY be high if there is no Vin. AGAIN AGAIN AGAIn. WHAT are you trying to achieve. WHAT IS WRONG with the std solution?

Comment: I am having the same issue here. Did you find a reliable solution that works?

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet the DW01A has "AUTO recovery" from standby mode. In other words the battery can be discharged again once it rises above the release voltage.

That's probably why the problem isn't commonly reported by people using those popular little TP4056 + DW01A boards as is.

FS312F has no auto recovery. The FS312MH does have auto recovery according to datasheet.

I know your question was basically to design a circuit that will short CS pin to ground when overdischarge is reached. This is beyond my capability but I had to answer the mystery about why this question seems a bit obscure. Probably not many have bothered to switch from the commonly used DW01A to FS312F thus running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

With N-Channel MOSFET Drain and Source between CS and VBAT- and also pull-down resistor between its Gate and VBAT-. You need a single pulse to turn on the Gate to short the pins.

One way to do that is with output of RC HPF with input from BAT pin. Make sure the ground of that HPF is BAT-. Adjust the value with trimmers so that the timing could turn on the gate properly.

The R in that HPF could also act as pull-down resistor. So in the end you just need 3 components to accomplish this, MOSFET, R and C.

It is stable because it's a single pulse right at the moment you insert the battery. If the battery is really below the overdischarge detection voltage then the IC still won't turn on the gate of that common-drain back-to-back MOSFET. So there won't be any oscillations.